# Trouble Configuring Python Tk Window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to configure a Tk window to a dark gray color and am having problems with my for loop, here is the code...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

MessageSettings = ["#141414", "#ffffa6"]

for (backhex, forhex) in MessageSettings:
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.title("Binary Suite")
    win.config(hight=10, width=15)
    message = Label(win, text="This is a demo provided by \n" + "Binary Digits")
    message.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    message.config(bg=backhex, fg=forhex, font=("system", 14, "normal"))

root.title("Binary Suite")
root.config(cursor="cross")
Label(root, text="Property of Binary Digits, /n" + "a part of Silicon Industries").pack(side=TOP)
quit = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.quit).pack()
quit.config(relief=GROOVE)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the program, I receive an error message that says...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...
    for (backhex,forhex) in MessageSettings:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `for (x,y) in z`, z is expected to be a list of lists. You are giving it only a single list. To fix the problem you are reporting, make that into a list of lists:

```
MessageSettings = [["#141414", "#ffffa6"]]
```

This problem isn't related at all to tkinter, it's just how python works.

You have a few other problems in your code. You misspelled "height" as "hight". Also, when you do something like `quit = Button(...).pack()`, "quit" will have the value `None` since that's what `.pack()` returns. You need call `pack` in a separate statement.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a terrible speller.